# Understanding RASA dialog flow REST APIs

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I think this will be a very basic question. But I'm little confused. So, can anybody help me to understand this?

Assume there is a bot story like below:

User; **Hi**

Bot: **How can I help**

User: I want to know the current weather in New York.

Bot: Sure give me a sec...

Bot: The current temp is 20c

User: Thanks

and I'm running the rasa core server and using the REST API **localhost:5005/conversations/default/parse** to get the response but here I'm not getting the actual bot message responses.

i.e., If I am sending the input as **Hi** to that API, in the response I am getting a json but none of the fields has **How can I help** text.

How to get that message in the response do I need to use **localhost:5005/conversations/default/respond** to get that?

Anybody help me to understand the flow.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Please try using the [Rest channel](https://rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/#rest-channels):

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "message": "Hello"
}'
```

You should then get a response for the request, e.g.:

```
[
    {
        "recipient_id": "default",
        "text": "an answer from the bot."
    }
]
```